# look ahead function or use some parameters generated at other level function in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am having events : example : event1, event2, event3, event4 & event5 & when the process is executed event by event some of the parameters are encounters only at 5th event.

I want to use or push those parameters at 1st event or look ahead at the 1st event & use those parameters to take the decision.

How can we do this TCL? Can we use uplevel or upvar?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this is to use a global variable to hold the values that you wish to carry forward. The use of a global variable (or an array indexed by the original widget name, if that's sensible, which it often is) is OK because users tend to produce only a single sequence of events when interacting with a program. A good example of this is in a drag-and-drop system.

```
bind .abc <ButtonPress-1>   {startDrag %W %X %Y}
bind .abc <B1-Motion>       {continueDrag %W %X %Y}
bind .abc <ButtonRelease-1> {finishDrag %W %X %Y}

proc startDrag {w x y} {
    global drag
    set drag(origin,$w) [list $x $y]
    # Other stuff to change cursors, setup drag indicators, etc.
    puts "started drag from ($x,$y) where the widget is $w"
}
proc continueDrag {w x y} {
    global drag
    lassign $drag(origin,$w) originalX originalY
    # Update any drag/drop indicators
    puts "dragged from ($originalX,$originalY) to ($x,$y) where the widget is '[winfo containing $x $y]'"
}
proc finishDrag {w x y} {
    global drag
    lassign $drag(origin,$w) originalX originalY
    # Do the drop
    puts "dropped at ($x,$y) over '[winfo containing $x $y]' with a drag that started at ($originalX,$originalY)"
    # Clean up the global(s); not required, but a good habit...
    unset drag(origin,$w)
}
```

Tk uses this sort of thing internally quite a bit. You could also use a global directly to keep the widget, but that's unnecessary with drag-and-drop because of the automatically-applied `grab` that's applied whenever a mouse button is down (little-known features of windowing systems…)

Comment: Hello Donal, THank you for the answer....but I am only using tcl & not tk.